# SAGA Raster Mosaic Issue with output (projection/not showing)

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, saga, mosaic

I am trying to create a mosaic from a couple of georeferenced raster images (old aerial photos) using the SAGA mosaic raster layers function from the QGIS toolbox. Project and layers are all on the same CRS (EPSG:4674). I kept the default settings from the SAGA Mosaic Raster Layers window and processing runs smoothly. However, the mosaic output layer (named 'Grid') does not show on the project CRS nor when I "go to layer". In properties, the output's CRS is the same as other layers and project.

Any ideas of what might be happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand : what do you mean by "mosaic output" ?

Comment: Just to clarify - by saying "did not change anything", do you mean you have kept default cellsize (e.g. 100.0) untouched?  Because the CRS (EPSG 4674) seems to be in degree (latlong), you may want to use smaller cell size (like 0.001?).

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies! The problem was the cell size settings. I have tried smaller sizes such as 0.001 and smaller and it works perfectly. I have edited the question to clarify. Cheers!

Comment: Great! Care to share your experience of tackling this issue by posting it as answer?